# Appending Byte[] to end of a binary file

Tags: java, append, dataoutputstream

I'm parsing a file.  I'm creating a new output file and will have to add the 'byte[] data' to it.  From there I will need to append many many other 'byte[] data's to the end of the file.  I'm thinking I'll get the user to add a command line parameter for the output file name as I already have them providing the file name which we are parsing.  That being said if the file name is not yet created in the system I feel I should generate one.

Now, I have no idea how to do this.  My program is currently using DataInputStream to get and parse the file.  Can I use DataOutputStream to append?  If so I'm wondering how I would append to the file and not overwrite.

Comment: The critical thing is how you open the file.  You must open for append vs simple output.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

> If so I'm wondering how I would append to the file and not overwrite.

That's easy - and you don't even need `DataOutputStream`. Just `FileOutputStream` is fine, using [the constructor with an `append` parameter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream%28java.lang.String,%20boolean%29):

```
FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("filename", true);
try {
   output.write(data);
} finally {
   output.close();
}
```

Or using Java 7's [try-with-resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html):

```
try (FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("filename", true)) {
    output.write(data);
}
```

If you *do* need `DataOutputStream` for some reason, you can just wrap a `FileOutputStream` opened in the same way.

Comment: Awesome thanks!  The second true parameter is the appened option I assume?  Just checked, yup!

Comment: @johnstamos: Yup - follow the link in the answer.

Comment: Thanks. And this also work for android!! adding a point! :-)

Answer (score 5):

```
Files.write(new Path('/path/to/file'), byteArray, StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
```

This is for byte append. Don't forget about Exception

Comment: Welcome to SO, and thanks for proving an answer. This is up for review in the low quality posts queue because it is a code only answer, and we don't really like those. If you want to join in, then you are welcome, but you have to put a little more effort into your answers. We expect code to be surrounded by an explanation of how it solves the OP's problem. If you like, you can read [ask] and [answer] to clear things up a bit. Ty for your time.

Comment: Files.write(Paths.get("/var/error.txt"), byteArray, StandardOpenOption.APPEND);

Use this snippet

Answer (score 1):

```
File file =new File("your-file");
FileWriter fileWritter = new FileWriter(file.getName(),true);
BufferedWriter bufferWritter = new BufferedWriter(fileWritter);
bufferWritter.write(your-string);
bufferWritter.close();
```

Of coruse put this in try - catch block.